# Grafana template showing data only for remote and local hosts data but not for containers when drop down doesnot have IP showing

Tags: grafana, prometheus, grafana-templating, grafana-api

1. I have **Prometheus** with node-exporter, cdvisor and grafana on same instance.
2. I have other instances with node and cadvisor for collecting metrics to grafana.

Now I have created a grafana template that accepts the Instance name:

**As We have 2 instance here : The template is showing following in drop down**

[image]

1. ip address of second instance
2. Node-exporter incase of first instance

So when selecting the instance with IP it works great but incase of instance showing with name node-exporter its not working. It works if I manually pass code-advisor to the query .

**Here is the query:**

```
count(container_last_seen{instance=~"$server:.*",image!=""})
```

> Here is the prometheus.yml file where all the targets are set as the
>   node-exporter runs in the same instance where prometheus is I have
>   used localhost there. Please check bellow

**prometheus.yml**

global:
  scrape_interval: 5s
  external_labels:
    monitor: 'my-monitor'

scrape_configs:
    - job_name: 'prometheus'
      static_configs: 
       - targets: ['localhost:9090']

```
- job_name: 'node-exporter'
  static_configs:
    - targets: ['node-exporter:9100']

- job_name: 'lab2'
  static_configs:
    - targets: ['52.32.2.X:9100']

- job_name: 'cadvisor'
  static_configs:
    - targets: ['52.32.2.X:8080','cadvisor:8080']
```

*If I try to edit targets and add localhost instead of node-exporter it doesnot even show up in drop down than*

***The node selections is working well for the HOST metrics but not for the containers metrics.***

*NOTE: It is working for the containers whose IP is shown in drop down but not for host not showing ip*